# Motorola barcode scanner

Tags: c#, windows-ce, barcode-scanner, motorola

I have Motorola m55, barcode scanner is only active in when I run demo app for barcode scanner. Now I am planing to create remote desktop app for scanning, so is there a way to make barcode active all the time on this device.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into product documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Before planning, please ask the vendor whether it can do it or not.

Regarding WindowsCE / WindowsMobile and its remote desktop, it depends strongly on each products, and there is insufficient with the usual knowledge of Windows for PC.